# How many different item in my arraylist without using hashset?

Tags: java, list, methods, arraylist

I would like to know if there is a method in java to count how many DIFFERENT item i have in my ArrayList without using hashset?

If there is not how can i create one to count how many DIFFERENT item there is in my ArrayList  without using hashset?

Thank You

Comment: Did you try to do something on your own? Or at least do some research on this topic. I think googling with the title itself will give you so many answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using a Set

Sets are typically used to have a collection with unique items. You can use this property this way:

```
List<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> temporarySet = new HashSet<>();
temporarySet.addAll(myArrayList);
int uniqueCount = temporarySet.size();
```

#### Using Collections.sort()

If all your list items implements Comparable, you can sort the list beforehand and then count successive items which are non equals.

```
private static int getUniqueCountUsingSort(List<String> list) {
    if (list.size() < 2) { // obvious case.
        return list.size();
    }

    List<String> listCopy = new ArrayList<>(list);
    Collections.sort(listCopy);
    int uniqueCount = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < listCopy.size(); i++) { // starts at 1.
                    // Compare with previous item in the sorted list.
        if (!listCopy.get(i).equals(listCopy.get(i-1))) {
            uniqueCount ++;
        }
    }
    return uniqueCount;
}
```

This method has the same performance characteristics as the Set method because Collections.sort() is O(n log(n)).

#### By hand

You can also simply do it the hard way, but it is slower O(n^2):

```
private static int getUniqueCountByHand(List<String> list) {

    int uniqueCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        boolean isUnique = true;
        // look if there is another entity before that is equal to this one.
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (list.get(j).equals(list.get(i))) {
                isUnique = false;
            }
        }
        if (isUnique) {
            uniqueCount ++;
        }
    }

    return uniqueCount;
}
```

Comment: +1 Very clever idea, I like it :)

Comment: Why are you adding the arraylist elements again to the set? Since you are already passing it to the constructor.

Comment: @RohitJain Ah yes, thank you. In the middle of writing this, I was thinking it would be more clear if I used "addAll". Then I forgot to remove the thing in the constructor.

Comment: is there a way without using hashset ?

Comment: This is the idiomatic way and its complexity is O(n log(n)). If you want to not use HashSet, then you either have to implement an equivalent of HashSet for that purpose or use a slower quadratic algorithm. I am going to edit my answer to show you that if you want.

Answer (score 5):

`new HashSet<NestedItem>(theList).size()` should suit your needs, since a `Set` automatically removes duplicated nested items.

In a generic way:

```java
public static <E> int uniqueCount(final List<E> list) {
    return new HashSet<E>(list).size();
}
```

Make sure to implement the equals/hashCode methods of the nested type the way you need.

Answer (score 3):

#### Add the items from your list into a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and check its size.

```
new HashSet(myListOfItems).size(); // => number of unique elements
```

Answer (score 0):

list is an List (ArrayList) of Object.
To count the unique objects:

```
Set set = new HashSet(list);
int cnt = set.size();
```

Variable cnt now contains the number of unique elements.

Even shorter:

```
int cnt = new HashSet(list).size();
```

Sets contains only unique items.

Comment: This is not valid in Java!

Comment: @Eng.Fouad Updated now shorted and correct

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a HashSet if you don't need different items. Besides that, just sweep through and add them to a separate list if it doesn't already contain it. It would take about roughly O(n + n/2) time to do that though.